# Different results on anomaly detection bettween pycaret and H2O

Tags: python, h2o, anomaly-detection, pycaret

I'm working on detect anomalies from the following data:
[image]

It comes from a processed signal of and hydraulic system, from there I know that the dots in the red boxes are anomalies happen when the system fails.

I'm using the first 3k records to train a model, both in pycaret and H20. These 3k records covers 5 cycles of data, as shown in the image bellow:

To train the model in pycaret I'm using the following code:

[image]

```
from pycaret.anomaly import *
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
import pandas as pd
exp_ano101 = setup(df[["Pressure_median_mw_2500_ac"]][0:3000], normalize = True, 
                   session_id = 123)

iforest = create_model('iforest')
unseen_predictions = predict_model(iforest, data=df[["Pressure_median_mw_2500_ac"]])
unseen_predictions = unseen_predictions.reset_index()
```

The results I get from pycaret are pretty good:

[image]

And with a bit of post processing I can get the follwing, which is quite close to the ideal:

[image]

On the other hand, using H20, with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from h2o.estimators import H2OIsolationForestEstimator, H2OGenericEstimator
import tempfile
ifr = H2OIsolationForestEstimator()
ifr.train(x="Pressure_median_mw_2500_ac",training_frame=hf)
th = df["mean_length"][0:3000].quantile(0.05)
df["anomaly"] = df["mean_length"].apply(lambda x: "1" if x> th  else "0")
```

I get this:

[image]

Which is a huge difference, since it is not detecting as anomalies this block:

[image]

My doubt is, how can I get similar results that the ones I get from pycaret given that I'm using the same algorithm, which is Isolation Forest. And even using SVM in Pycaret I get closer results than using isolation forest in H2O

[image]

Comment: Is this time-series data, or are each of these independent samples?

Comment: @JonNordby it Is time series, it comes from a periodic industrial process

Comment: Probably some small parameter tuning might allow the models to converge. Also just checking, the data was normalized for the H20 approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: your problem would be massively simplified by changing the instances to detect anomalies to be cycles, not individual data samples from sensor. The differences between existing applied methods are probably due to differences in hyper-parameters, and the sensitivity to hyperparameters due to the less-than-ideal problem specification.

This is a time-series, and your anomalies seem to be stateful - that is an anomaly starts to occur, and then affects many time-steps, then recovers again. However, you appear to be trying to detect anomalies in individual time-steps / samples, which will not work well, because in the anomalous condition the highest values are still within the normal range of individual datapoints from a normal condition. Furthermore there are strong temporal patterns in your data for the normal condition, and these are not possible to model with such an approach. That different softwares give different not-so-good results is expected, as tradeoffs will have to be made, and different hyperparameters will influence this.

What you should do is to transform your original time-series to get instances that are more meaningful than individual point samples. The best for this kind of cyclic process with strong similarities between cycles, is to transform into a time-series for each cycle. This requires knowing (or reliably detecting) when a cycle starts.

If cycle start is not available, one can instead use a sliding window approach, where the window is long enough to cover one or more cycles.

Once you have such a set of windows, one can think about doing anomaly detection on it. Start with computing basic statistics that summaries the window (mean,std,min,max,max-min etc). The anomalies you have shown as an example will be trivially separable by the mean value of the cycle (or max or min). Don't need a isolation forest even, a Gaussian Mixture Model will do just fine, and allow for more interpretable results. This should work across a wide range of models and hyperparamters.

Once a basic solution that captures such large discrepancies are in place, one can consider going further. Adding a sequence model autoencoder would for example be able to pick up much smaller deviations, if one has enough data.

Answer (score 2):

Pycaret uses for anomaly detection the library PyOD. It is then PyOD vs H2O. Maybe there are different default parameters. In Pycaret (PyOD) could be modified the parameter fraction  - default = 0.05, the percentage / proportion of outliers in the dataset.

You should try to play with this parameter und perhaps you get the same results from both libraries.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you'd need to provide particular versions of each library as implementation of isolation forest and thus results might differ between PyOD versions.

Other than that try to see first if results of running isolation forest alone in PyOD and in H2O are consistently the same - maybe it's more of a random number generator / state issue than implementation difference.

Apart from validating parameters I recommend you to take a look at code of these libraries - likely it's difference between default parameter values: https://pyod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyod/models/iforest.html